# How to manipulate MP3 tags only with client side coding?

Tags: mp3, client-side, meta-tags

I am trying to manipulate mp3 tags on a certain web service that is running on rails.

No problem if I could upload the mp3 on to the server and handle it locally, but this is not the case.

I want to be able to select, manipulate and save mp3s solely on the client side, preferably on JavaScript, but anything client side will do.

I know there are techniques on manipulating local files client side, but is there any knowledge on how to do this on mp3?

Comment: javascript is the only server side script that you should rely on. :)

Comment: ^^ oupps The only client Side Script :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible unless you make a flash player that can change the tags, and then give it to the user via a download. I'm not sure for an example as I don't play with flash at all :)

But server side scripts will help you there, I think all you would need to do is add an extra http-header or use a php class that lets you modify the tags. if you need them to be dynamic that is the only real option that I can think of for you.

Sorry if that is not what you wanted to hear, but its all I can think of for an option.

Comment: well I had a feeling it would be this, tried many things to avert it but I have came to the same conclusion.